# Can an arbitrary target fps range be specified with Camera2 API?

Tags: android, android-camera2

In our mobile application, camera capture on the Android device is sent as a video stream to a remote server.

I need to automatically adapt my camera fps to the network speed. Basically, if I detect that the network is slow, I need to reduce the fps and keep reducing it until a balance is reached.

I obtain available fps ranges using the field `CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES` on Camera2 API. I set the target fps using `CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE` field.

Let's say the possible list of ranges, for example, is (30, 30) and (15, 30).

I started by setting the target with the highest fps ((30, 30) in our case). Once I detected that the network is slow, I reduced the fps range to (15, 30). However, what I noticed is that the device continued to generate about 29 fps.

As an experiment, I forced the target fps value to be (15, 15). This seems to have done the trick. The system started to generate 15 fps, a value that I was expecting.

However, this makes me wonder what really is the relationship between `CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES` and `CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE`. My impression was that the target 
range that is set on the camera has to be one of the values received from  `CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES`. This would be either (30, 30) or (15, 30) in my case. However, if (15, 15) is also being accepted as a valid target fps, I wonder if I can specify any range inside a valid range. For example, I would like to set the fps to (29, 29), (28, 28), and so on until a balance is reached. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the answer is **NO**.

The contract requires that all supported FPS ranges be published in `CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES`. Furthermore, the behavior of the device is *undefined* when you choose an unsupported camera parameter, e.g. frame rate or preview size. Some device will throw a RuntimeException, another could keep the current setting, yet another will choose something *'as close as possible to what you ask'*.

Some devices don't publish *all* supported FPS ranges, but also the API is not always possible to implement to the letter. For example, consider a camera that can deliver full HD 1920x1080 frames at 30 FPS, but for smaller 1280x720 frames supports 60 FPS? Which supported FPS ranges should it publish? What if these setting depend on some other choices, like night scene mode, or on focus distance?

And I have not yet spoken about the bugs that often happen on less polished devices. It isn't uncommon to see a device that declares some supported FPS or size is supported, but actually fails to set it (again, with a variety of results).

If your application or library intends to cover millions of users with a wide variety of hardware, you have no choice but to keep certain white-lists and black-lists for device features that may and may not be used, that take into account the manufacturer, the device model, and sometimes even the system version (e.g. I have seen over-the-air upgrades that broke certain, admittedly marginal, camera features).

Another note is that floating FPS ranges cannot be used for video recording or transmission. If you choose (15, 30) range, you will have problems with many video players, the audio will never be in sync with video, and you will still have no control of the bitrate.

---

**TL;NR:** in your specific case, there is no need to bother with <s>unsupported</s> undocumented (15, 15) FPS range. You can easily *drop* every second frame, and pass 15 FPS to the network, still keeping the supported (30, 30) range. If you need an arbitrary uniform rate of, say, 20 FPS, you are less lucky. There are ways to delay delivery of next frame a bit, but nobody will guarantee that exactly 50000000 nanoseconds will pass between these frames.